# In functions that call a check function, where should the error message be generated/printed/sent?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, error-handling

I have started questioning if the way I handle errors is correct or pythonic. The code scenarios below are easy in nature, whilst the actual use would be more in line with discord.py and PRAW (reddit). The boolean indicates success, and the message returned is a message summarising the exception triggered.

Which of the following scenarios (WITH VERY SIMPLIFIED FUNCTIONS) is the proper pythonic way of doing it, or is there none? Or one I haven't thought of/learned yet?

---

Scenario 1: Main function returns on false from check function, but check function prints message

```py
def main_function():
    # calls the check function
    success = check_function(1, 2)
    if not success:
        return

def check_function(intone, inttwo):
    if intone != inttwo:
        print("Not the same")
        return False
    return True
```

---

Scenario 2: The main functions prints an error message based on boolean returned from check function

```py
def main_function():
    # calls the check function
    success = check_function(1, 2)
    if not success:
        print("Failure, not the same")
        return

def check_function(intone, inttwo):
    if intone != inttwo:
        return False
    return True
```

---

Scenario 3: The check function returns a boolean and a generated error message which the main function prints if false.

```py
def main_function():
    # calls the check function
    success, error = check_function(1, 2)
    if not success:
        print(error)
        return

def check_function(intone, inttwo):
    if intone != inttwo:
        return False, "Not the same"
    return True
```

---

Obviously, the coding I'm doing that made me think about this is slightly more complicated, but I believe the examples are carried over.

Comment: Scenario 2 is just about the best since it is the simplest. Scenario 3 will come into its own when there are multiple possible error messages to return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If sounds like you are used to outputting a Boolean for whether things went well or not.

If an error occurs, then you output `False`, or `True`.

Additionally, if there is an an error, you are using `print()` statements to display the error.

An example of pseudo-code using an approach similar to yours is shown below:

```python
# define function for baking a cake:   
     
def make_a_pancake():
    """
    outputs an ordered pair (`ec`, cake)
        `ec` is an error code
         If `ec` is zero, then `cake` is a finished cake

    ERROR CODES:
        0 - EVERYTHING WENT WELL
        1 - NO MIXING BOWLS AVAILABLE
        2 - WE NEED TO GET SOME EGGS
        3 - WE NEED TO GET SOME FLOUR
    """
    # IF THERE IS A MIXING BOWL AVAILABLE:
    #    GET OUT A MIXING BOWL

    if kitchen.has(1, "bowl"):
         my_bowl = kitchen.pop(1, "bowl")   

    else: # no mixing bowl available
        print("WE NEED A MIXING BOWL TO MAKE A CAKE")
        return 1 # NO MIXING BOWL IS AVAILABLE

    # IF THERE ARE EGGS AVAILABLE:
    #    PUT THE EGGS INTO THE BOWL

    if kitchen.has(6, "eggs"):
        my_eggs = kitchen.pop(6, "eggs")
        my_bowl.insert(my_eggs)
    else: # OUT OF EGGS
        print("RAN OUT OF EGGS. NEED MORE EGGS")
        return 2 

    # IF THERE IS WHEAT FLOUR AVAILABLE:
        # put 2 cups of flour into the bowl

    if len(kitchen.peek("flour")) > 0:
        f = kitchen.pop("flour", 2, "cups")
        my_bowl.insert(f)
    else:
       print("NOT ENOUGH FLOUR IS AVAILABLE TO MAKE A CAKE")
       RETURN 3, None

    # stir the eggs and flour inside of the bowl
    # stir 3 times

    for _ in range(0, 3):
        bowl.stir()

    # pour the cake batter from the bowl into a pan
    my_batter = bowl.pop()
    pan.push(my_batter)

    # cook the cake
    stove.push(pan)
    stove.turn_on()
    stove.turn_off()
    the_cake = pan.pop()

    return err_code, the_cake
```

The code above is similar to the way code was written many decades ago.

Usually,

- `0` is interpreted as `False`
- `1`, `2`, `3`, `etc`... are all `True`.

It might be confusing that `0` means `no error occurred`
However,

> There is only one way for things to go right.
> There are many ways for things to go wrong.

Every program written in python, Java, C++, C#, etc... will give the operating system (Microsoft windows, Linux, etc...) an error code when the whole program is done running.

- A "*clear*" error flag (zero) is good.
- An error flag of 1, 2, 3, ..., 55, ... 193, etc... is bad.

The most pythonic way to handle printing error messages is something you have not learned about yet.

It is called, ***exception handling***
It looks like the following:

```python
class NO_MORE_EGGS(Exception):         
    pass     

def cook_omelet():
    # if (THERE ARE NO EGGS):
    #     raise an exception

    if(kitchen.peek("eggs") < 1):
        msg = "you cannot make an omelet without breaking some eggs"
        raise NO_MORE_EGGS(msg)
    pan.push(eggs)  

    # cook the cake
    stove.push(pan)  # `push` means `insert` or `give`
    stove.turn_on()
    stove.turn_off()
    pan = stove.pop()
    the_omelet = pan.pop()

    return the_omelet
```

Ideally, a function is like a small component in a larger machine.

For example, a car, or truck, contains many smaller components:

- Alternators
- Stereos (for music)
- Radiator (to lower the engine temperature)
- Brake-pads

Suppose that Bob designs a stereo for a car made by a company named "Ford."

Ideally, I can take the stereo Bob designed put the stereo in a design for a different car.

A function is also like a piece of equipment in a kitchen.
Examples of kitchen equipment might be:

- A rice-cooker
- A toaster
- A kitchen sink

Suppose that you design a rice-cooker which works in Sarah's kitchen.
However, your rice-cooker does not work in Bob's kitchen.
That would be a very badly designed rice-cooker.
A well designed rice-cooker works in anybody's kitchen.

If you write a function in Python, then someone else should be able to use the function you wrote in somebody else's code.

For example, suppose you write a function to calculate the volume of a sphere.

If I cannot re-use your function in someone else's computer program, then you did a bad job writing your function.

A well-written function can be used in many, many, many different computer programs.

If you write a function containing `print` statements, that is a very bad idea.

Suppose you make a website to teach children about math.
Children type the radius of a sphere into the website.
The website calculates the volume of the sphere.
The website prints "The volume of the sphere is 5.11 cubic meters"

```python
import math

def calc_sphere_vol(radius):
    T = type(radius)
    rad_cubed = radius**T(3)
    vol = T(4)/T(3)*T(math.pi)*rad_cubed
    print("the volume of the sphere is", vol)
    return vol
```

In a different computer program, people want to calculate the radius of a sphere, quickly and easily without seeing any message printed to the console.

Maybe calculating the volume of a sphere is one tiny step on the way to a larger more complicated result.

A function should only print message to the console if the person using the function given the function permission to do so.

Suppose that:

1. you write some code.
2. you post your code on Github
3. I download your code from Github.

I should be able to run your code without seeing a single print statement (if I want to).

I should not have to re-write your code to turn-off the print statements.

Imagine that you were paid to design next year's model of some type of car.

You should not have to look inside the radio/stereo-system.
IF you are designing a large system, you should not have to see what is inside each small component.

A computer program is too big and complicated to re-write the code inside of the existing functions.

Imagine pieces of a computer program as small black cubes, or boxes.
Each box has input USB ports.
Each box has output USB ports.

I should be able to plug in any wires I want into the small box you designed and built.

I should never have to open up the box and re-wire the inside.

A computer programmer should be able to change where output from a function goes without modifying the code inside of that function.

`print` statements are very very bad.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid option 1 in the majority of cases. By having it do the reporting, you're limiting how it can be used in the future. What if you want this function to be used in a tkinter app later? Is `print`ing still appropriate? If the function's job is to do a check, it should just do the check. The caller can figure out how they want to use the returned boolean.

Options 2 and 3 are both viable, but which you'd use would depend on the case.

- If there's exactly one way in which a function can fail, or all different failures should be treated the same, a simple `False` is fine, since `False` implies the single failure reason.
- If there's multiple distinct ways in which a function can fail, returning some failure indicator that allows for multiple reasons would be better. A return of type `Union[bool, str]` may be appropriate for some cases; although I don't thinks strings make for good error types since they can be typo'd. I think a tuple of `Union[bool, ErrorEnum]` would be better; where `ErrorEnum` is some `enum.Enum` that can take a restricted set of possible values.

Options 3 bears a weak resemblence to Haskell's [`Maybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html) and [`Either`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-Either.html) types. If you're interested in different ways of error-handling, seeing how the "other side of the pond" handles errors may be enlightening. Here's a similar example to what you have from the `Either` link:

```
>>> import Data.Char ( digitToInt, isDigit )
>>> :{
    let parseEither :: Char -> Either String Int
        parseEither c
          | isDigit c = Right (digitToInt c)
          | otherwise = Left "parse error"
>>> :}
```

`parseEither` returns either a parsed integer, or a string representing an error.